# SQL Query - how to select count all value from table and displaying all counted and its id?

Tags: sql, syntax, count

I want to know if there's possible to displaying counting value from table and displaying it with itself id.

I'm not good in `PHP` code so I need help here,

**Problem**

*Example*

data in `nilai_3` table :

```
|-------|----|
| Nilai | ID |
|-------|----|
|   1   | 3  |
|   1   | 3  |
|   1   | 3  |
|   2   | 3  |
|   2   | 3  |
|   2   | 3  |
|   1   | 1  |
|   1   | 1  |
|   1   | 1  |
|   2   | 1  |
|   2   | 1  |
|-------|----|
```

how to make it showing like this

```
|-------|----|
| Nilai | ID |
|-------|----|
|   3   | 3  | //counting value 1 from nilai table but the id still not change
|   3   | 3  | //Counting value 2 from nilai table but the id still not change
|   3   | 1  |
|   2   | 1  |
|-------|----|
```

I just know how to counting nilai value with this code:
`SELECT COUNT( nilai )FROM nilai_3`

but when i modify the code using this:
`SELECT COUNT( nilai ) , id FROM nilai_3 where nilai=1, id=id`

its showing null value of id.

please help me how to fix it.

Comment: I believe your question is a SQL question. Might be worth updating your questions tags

Comment: thanks for the suggest, ill change it now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use group by

```
SELECT COUNT( * ), min(ID)
FROM nilai_3 
group by Nilai
```

for your second question

The correct sintax is with AND for the second  condition   (and not , comma) eg:

```
SELECT COUNT( nilai ) , id FROM nilai_3 
where nilai=1
AND  id=id
```

but id=id is always true so  you filter should be based only on

```
SELECT COUNT( nilai ) , id FROM nilai_3 
where nilai=1
```

Comment: what the function of syntax `min(id)` sir??

Comment: The function of min(id) is beacase  there is a group by and then  is requiree   aggregation function ..It 'a trick in order to have a value when you need to use aggregate functions  ..  otherwise  .. the query became more complex ..

Comment: i've edited my question on example table to be more complex, may you help me to solve that sir?

Comment: I thought I had already provided an answer, change the question does not seem right. you should accept the answer and publish a new question.  bye

Comment: I'm afraid when I publish a new question, its would be marked as same question, thanks anyway for help me, up vote for ur answer, :)

Comment: The question seems to be a gaps-and-islands problem, counting consecutive rows with the same value.

Comment: For counting consecutive row with same  value you can't use sql .. because this kind of problem  is not based on relational algebra .. (is not  baset on set theory ) you must use a procedural approach.. alias .. select the value and server  side  count the sequential  consecutive row based in you criteria ..